# C code randomize

Tags: c

I am trying to randomize a variable and then trying to use it in the functions where I want to use. But, when I put the randomized variable in for loop like below and when I use that in the function that I want to then it gives me error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "time.h"

void main (void) { 
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    srand( time(NULL )); 
    float r;
    r = rand()*1000;
  }

  write(abc, r);
  read(abc, r);
  write(xyz, r); 
  read(xyz, r);
}
```

So, when I use r from the for loop I get the error below:

```
In function 'void sim()':
'r' was not declared in this scope
```

But, when I remove `r` from the for loop then there is not any error. But, I want for loop so as to have different data for every write function.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean `r+=`? Running this 4 times won't make it anymore random. Also, you need to declare it outside of your loop, `r` that is

Comment: Please read into `rand` and `srand`. Your re-initialization of the state of the random generator is completely useless inside the `for` loop. There are good chances that many of your calls to `srand` fall to the same value with respect to the time precision.

Comment: Why is this down voted so much?

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher Didn't downvote, but the question makes little sense together with the code. Running srand/rand in a loop like this will only assign r the same value 4 times, not give 4 different values as it seems the asker wants.

Comment: Also srand() must be called once, and only once. NEVER inside a loop.

Answer (score 3):

`r` is a local variable for the loop and it is not visible outside of the loop. To fix this place its declaration(`float r;`) before the loop.

Comment: Hi everyone, ok. I moved srand outside the for loop and also declare r out of the for loop. It worked the way I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The scope of r is only inside the for loop.  Declare it prior to the loop, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yes, thanks ben & lvaylo it worked.